# Como concatenar duas Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenação-de-string

Como concatenar duas datas do tipo `DateTime`, sendo que uma delas pode ter seu valor igual a ***NULL***, estou tentando da seguinte forma;

```
DECLARE @DATA1 DATETIME = GETDATE(), @DATA2 DATETIME    
select  Convert(nvarchar(50),@DATA1 , 121) +'|'+ Convert(nvarchar(50), @DATA2, 121)
```

Mas isso retorna `null`, quando na realidade queria o valor do *GETDATE() + algo como vazio ou null.*

Comment: Tudo que você concatenar com NULL vai resultar em NULL, então você precisa primeiro mudar o null para outra coisa, e daí concatenar. A resposta do @Ricardo está correta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Então, eu tentei com [ISNULL()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Aqui funcionou:

```
DECLARE @DATA1 DATETIME = GETDATE(), @DATA2 DATETIME    
select  Convert(nvarchar(50),@DATA1 , 121) +'|'+ isnull(Convert(nvarchar(50), @DATA2, 121),'')
```

Comment: Além de *ISNULL*, você pode usar `COALESCE`, que dá o mesmo resultado e é uma função padrão ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @DATA1 DATETIME, @DATA2 DATETIME;
SET @DATA1 = getdate()
SET @DATA2 = null
SELECT  CASE WHEN (@DATA1 IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE Convert(nvarchar(50),@DATA1 , 121) END +'|'+ CASE WHEN (@DATA2 is null) THEN '' ELSE Convert(nvarchar(50), @DATA2, 121) END
```